# Hungarian algorithm for a single set

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I tried to adjust a hungarian algorithm in such a way that assignments among a single set are generated, according to https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268292864_The_Hungarian_Algorithm_with_a_Single_Input_Set. But after trying a lot I guess it is just not possible through several reasons: One thing a bipartite algorithm cannot/should not handle slings respectively odd-cycles and, of course, not disjoint sets.
Their approach is quite simple and also nice - at the first view. The Ansatz is just to mirror each time each edge (in a separate equality graph/matching) which enters the equality graph/matching. And the matching is perfect when all vertices are in one of both matchings.
But as I said I really tried - all - kind of possibilities to get it work..  but it won't. Since I invested a very lot of time I would like to know if I'm right that the approach cannot work.
Thank you in advance!

edit: I found on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972936/hungarian-algorithm-on-symmetric-matrix that one had the same question with the same implementation. But I still lack an proof of this approach.